# Show console for python script executed from entry point in linux?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, console, entry-point

**How does one show the console running a python script from an entry point in Linux?**

I have a python package with various entry-points as `console_scripts` defined in my `setup.py` file as shown:

```py
entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'pylabnet=pylabnet.launchers.launch_control:main',
            'pylabnet_proxy=pylabnet.launchers.launch_control:main_proxy'
            ]
        },
```

In one of my methods (`launch_control:main_proxy`), I prompt the user for input via the console as shown:

```py
self.host = input('Please enter the master Launch Control IP address:\n>> ')
```

If I run `launch_control.main_proxy` directly from a terminal, I can use that terminal for this input. However, if I launch the script using the executable created by `setup.py`, the console is automatically hidden.

**Is there a way to manually show and/or hide the console associated with a python process from within python script in Linux (specifically Ubuntu 20.04)?**

For example, in Windows, I can use Windows-specific commands to hide/show the console from a python process as shown:

```py
def show_console():
    ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 9)

def hide_console():
    ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
```

Does something similar exist in a Linux environment? Apologies in advance if this is a basic Linux question - I am relatively new to Linux and trying to make my previously Windows-only python package Linux compatible